# Create columns from the result of generate_series in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I feel like this should be very straightforward, but I cannot seem to find a solution.

I am trying to create a plpgsql function that takes as input a start date and an end date, that then generates a series of years between the two dates that I can use as columns for my new table.

For example, if I call

```
my_function('2010-01-01', '2015-01-1')
```

I want a new table with columns 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, and 2015.

I'm inclined to use the generate_series() function to do this, but I cannot figure out how to actually store the values it returns and pull them out to create my table with.

I'm using Postgres 9.5.3

Comment: You need to provide some code showing what you have attempted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dynamic sql with `execute format`.

Assuming that the new table should have text columns:

```
create or replace function create_table(table_name text, from_year int, to_year int)
returns void language plpgsql as $$
begin
    execute format('create table %I(%s)', 
        table_name, 
        string_agg(concat('"', y::text, '" text'), ',')) 
    from generate_series(from_year, to_year) y;
end $$;

select create_table('my_table', 2010, 2015);

\d my_table

  Table "public.my_table"
 Column | Type | Modifiers 
--------+------+-----------
 2010   | text | 
 2011   | text | 
 2012   | text | 
 2013   | text | 
 2014   | text | 
 2015   | text |
```

Comment: would this approach be easily adaptable to add on these columns to an existing table, rather than creating a new one using them?

Comment: Sure, try something like this: `format('alter table %I %s', table_name, string_agg(concat('add column "', y::text, '" text'), ','))`

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    'create table t ("' || 
    string_agg (to_char(y,'YYYY'), '" text, "') ||
    '" text)'
from generate_series('2010-01-01'::date, '2015-01-1', '1 year') y(y)
;
                                           ?column?                                            
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 create table t ("2010" text, "2011" text, "2012" text, "2013" text, "2014" text, "2015" text)
(1 row)
```